# Is there any calculator with degrees, minutes and seconds calculation?

Tags: software-recommendation

I need a calculator software for calculating DMS (degree, minutes, seconds). Maybe something like this:

[image]

I need to use the calculator to calculate somthing like this easily:

```
87°43′41″ + 120°33′1″
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

How about [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/)? And maybe this [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1816058) can be helpful :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.